# 301 redirect from URL with GET-parameters to the homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, joomla1.5, getparameter

I have an old website with Joomla 1.5. It has some strange links with GET-parameters, like this:

```
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=1186511674
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=145388433
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=1553907057
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=1563973527
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=1981273478
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=2139631800
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=366928750
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=524689684
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=569077423
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=573405687
http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=879649167
```

I want make redirect theses links to the homepage.
I tried some different instructions in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/images/stories/catalog/?rand=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://primavista.ru/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/images/stories/catalog/?rand=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://primavista.ru/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(rand)=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/stories/catalog(/.*)?$ https://primavista.ru/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

But no one not working. Maybe here someone can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: It isn't user friendly or good for SEO to redirect bad URLs to the home page.   They should return a "404 Not Found" or "410 Gone" status, preferably with custom error page that explains why they are no longer available and lists alternatives.

Comment: Maybe you right. But how I can make redirect which will be work?

Comment: You shouldn't make such a redirect, so don't try to do so.

Comment: But I really need make redirect from these links

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain the purpose of this redirect?

Comment: Website has really many articles over 9000 and it very old.  Some articles has broken images and it generate these links. Fix all articles  - it really long time. I want make redirect

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} rand=\d+
RewriteRule ^/?images/stories/catalog/?$ / [R=301,L]
```

It is a good idea to start out with `R=302` temporary redirections and to only change that to `R=301` permanent redirections one you are satisfied with everything. That prevents nasty caching issues on the client side ...

UPDATE:
Your comment below indicates that you actually ask to remove the GET parameter in the redirected request, which you never mentioned before...

You can use the additional `QSD` flag for that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} rand=\d+
RewriteRule ^/?images/stories/catalog/?$ /? [R=301,QSD,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, but not working

Comment: And "not working" means what exactly? Do you get an unexpected response? No response at all? An error? Does the universe implode?

Comment: I have redirect on the homepage, but GET-parametr exist

Comment: You never mentioned an issue with that parameter before. If the issue is just removing that parameter then have a try using the variant I added as UPDATE to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried, but after redirect I'll look this URL: https://www.primavista.ru/?rand=1186511674

Comment: Please give an example for the request, the expected result and the actual result. We need to be precise here.

Comment: Example broken link: http://www.primavista.ru/images/stories/catalog/?rand=1186511674
Must be redirect on: https://primavista.ru

Comment: I made another slight change to the second, updated implementation. Have a try.

Comment: The same result. I go to the homepage with GET-parameter

Comment: No, things are fine now when I test the URL you gave above in the comment. Could it be that you are looking at cached results? Please test using a fresh anonymous browser window.